# C++ Шаблонные функции

Tags: c++

Я хочу написать универсальную функцию которая будет уметь выводить как одномерные так и двумерные массивы. Для этого использую шаблоны, все было окей пока не начал выводить двумерные массивы. Для определения типа переданного параметра использую typeid, но компилятор упорно не дает мне выводить двумерные и одномерные массивы в одной функции, помогите разобраться в чем проблема.
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



template <class T>
void printToConcole(T showingParam) {

    std::cout << (typeid(showingParam).name()) << std::endl;
    if (typeid(showingParam) == typeid(int)) {
        std::cout << showingParam << std::endl;
    }
    else if(typeid(showingParam) == typeid(double)) {
        std::cout << showingParam << std::endl;

    }
    else if (typeid(showingParam) == typeid(int*)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(showingParam) / sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            if (i== sizeof(showingParam) / sizeof(int)) {
                std::cout << showingParam[i] << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << showingParam[i] << '\t';
        }
    }
    else if (typeid(*showingParam) == typeid(int[sizeof(*showingParam)])) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(showingParam) / sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j <= sizeof(showingParam[i]) / sizeof(int); j++)
            {
            if (j == sizeof(showingParam[i]) / sizeof(int)) {
                std::cout << showingParam[i][j] << std::endl;
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << showingParam[i][j] << '\t';
            }
        }
    }
    
}


int main()
{
    
    int a[3] =  {4, 5, 6};
    printToConcole(a);
}
```

Ошибки компилятора:

```
prog.cpp(33,1): error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель
prog.cpp(36,1): error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель
```

Comment: если Вы пишите шаблонную функцию и используете typeid - Вы делаете что то не верно.

Comment: Компилироваться должны все ветки оператора `if-else`, даже те которые никогда не будут выполняться для заданных типов шаблонного параметра. Если хотите компилировать только те ветки, которые будут доступны используете  [/constexpr if statement/][https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if], но оператор сравнения для typeinfo будет constexpr только начиная с C++23. Поэтому путь тупиковый. Используйте перегрузку функций.

Comment: Да я бы с радостью использовал перегрузку функций, но программа обязательно требует использования хотябы одного шаблона.

Comment: @АлександрАрсеньев используйте шаблоны чтобы определить размер передаваемого (по константной ссылке) массива. А для интегральных типов - отдельный шаблон.

Comment: https://ideone.com/mmXgK0 не годится?

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам, может кому пригодится.
Ответ был в следующем, необходимо явное преобразование типов и все работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printIntArray(int * arr ){
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        if (i == sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << arr[i] << '\t';
    }
}






template <class T>
void printToConcole(T showingParam) {


    if (typeid(showingParam) == typeid(int)) {
        std::cout << showingParam << std::endl;
    }
    else if(typeid(showingParam) == typeid(double)) {
        std::cout << showingParam << std::endl;

    }
    else if ( typeid(showingParam) == typeid(int*) )
    {

        printIntArray((int*)showingParam);
        
    }
    else if (typeid(*showingParam) == typeid(int[sizeof(*showingParam) / sizeof(int)])) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(showingParam) / sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            printIntArray((int*)showingParam[i]);
        }
        
    }
    
}


int main()
{
    
    int a[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
    printToConcole(a);
}
```

Comment: хм, printIntArray даже правильно работает? Она будет печатать 3 элемента (на 64битной платформе). Она содержит две грубые ошибки прямо в одном месте.

Comment: В этом решении ошибки: (1) - из указателя int* - невозможно узнать число элементов данных, на которые он указывает.   `sizeof(arr) ` - размер указателя, а не данных. (2) `int a[3][3] ` - это  не `int* [3]`.

Comment: `typeid(*showingParam)` а как он это собрал? Можете пояснить?

Comment: у меня и gcc и clang это собрал. Ха, у автора массивы на три элемента и для него все работает:)

Comment: @pavel  тип `int[3][3]` при передаче в функцию, преобразовался в `int (*) [3]`. Из соображений совместимости с C, и потому что параметр передается по значению, а не по ссылке.

Comment: @Chorkov тут ещё ладно. а если обычный инт передать то как это собирать?)

Comment: Ни как оно не собирается

Comment: `if (typeid(x) == typeid(T))` стоит заменить на `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(x), T>)`.